# Unable to install seaborn on EMR cluster

Tags: pyspark, pip, seaborn, amazon-emr

I want to install pandas and seaborn on an EMR cluster with PySpark. I tried:

```
sc.install_pypi_package("pandas==1.0.3")
sc.install_pypi_package("seaborn==0.12.1")
```

Pandas worked. But seaborn did not. It asked to install Cython and I did.
However, it still did not work. It seems I need to install many more dependencies. See [output here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mkDm3aSltx7knkx-_9Jj2RrjLigbZFWV6TkAMigzq9A/edit?usp=sharing) (16 pages). Is there an easier way to install it?  I thought that  sc.install_pypi_package would install the dependencies.
Also, I tried `%pip install seaborn` as suggested by the [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-installing-libraries-and-kernels.html), but it did not work either.

Comment: It looks like it is trying to build numpy from source and failing while it's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I fixed it by providing a bootstrap script while launching my ERM cluster. Here is a sample that you could use for your purpose

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

cat > /var/tmp/fix-bootstap.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
set -x

while true; do
    NODEPROVISIONSTATE=`sed -n '/localInstance [{]/,/[}]/{
    /nodeProvisionCheckinRecord [{]/,/[}]/ {
    /status: / { p }
    /[}]/a
    }
    /[}]/a
    }' /emr/instance-controller/lib/info/job-flow-state.txt | awk ' { print $2 }'`

    if [ "$NODEPROVISIONSTATE" == "SUCCESSFUL" ]; then
        echo "Running my post provision bootstrap"
        # Enter your code here
        sudo yum install python-devel -y
        sudo yum install python3-devel -y
        sudo python3 -m pip install -U pip
        python3 -m pip install -U pip
        sudo python3 -m pip install cython
        sudo python3 -m pip install numpy
        sudo python3 -m pip install pandas
        sudo python3 -m pip install tsfresh
    sudo python3 -m pip install tables==3.6.1
    sudo python3 -m pip install xgboost==1.4.2
    sudo python3 -m pip install pyarrow==4.0.1
    sudo python3 -m pip install seaborn
        exit
    else
        echo "Sleeping Till Node is Provisioned"
        sleep 10
    fi
done

EOF

chmod +x /var/tmp/fix-bootstap.sh
nohup /var/tmp/fix-bootstap.sh  2>&1 &
```